# Regex for Valid Email address or Valid alpha numeric check

Tags: regex

Hi i have field called UserName into my MVC 3 Model. This propery could be valid email address or could be valid AlphaNumeric. How i can write Regex Express to check both things (Valid Email or Valid Alpha Numeric).

Valid Email Expresion which i am using is

```
"^[_a-zA-Z0-9\'-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9\'-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(name))$"
```

Comment: What regex implementation are you using?  Are there any restrictions on the contents of the email addresses or alphanumeric strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the alphanumeric string you want to match instead of an email address really is just `A-Z` and `0-9`, you can take what you have already...

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9\'-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9\'-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(name))$
```

...and wrap it in parenthesis with a pipe to indicate it as an optional group...

```
^([_a-zA-Z0-9\'-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9\'-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.(([0-9]{1,3})|([a-zA-Z]{2,3})|(name))|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

Which seems like an overly simplistic solution, give the work you have done so far, which makes me wonder if there is some catch to this???

Comment: what is correct syntex.   this throw error '(name))|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$' because of closing bracket before $ sign.  '(name))|[a-zA-Z0-9]+$' is it correct or its required to wrape into brackets.

Comment: The regex pattern as I have it here works when I test it.  Double-check that you did not accidentally remove any brackets or parenthesis when duplicating it.  What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

if you want alpha numeric(must contain single alpha and single numeric) try this

```
(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*)(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*)(^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$)
```